Jquery ui sortable - Programmatically move each pawn to it's own position
I've been trying to make a simple grid system with pawns (chess-like) for my dungeons and dragons sessions using jquery sortable. I am using laravel with blade for a project.
So in the code below, (which was given to me by another question) it creates a grid of certain area on which the player can freely move the pawns. I made it so an ajax request can save each of the pawn's coordinates to a database in the form of 0,1 or 3,4 etc.
Generally everything works but the problem is that I cannot programmatically set the position of each pawn. This is used not only to keep the positions after page refresh but it is used to be able to make the pawn positions visible to other people using the website.
So here is the code I got so far:


let gridSize = 7,
//characters array is empty usually because it gets all the pawn infos from the db
     characters = [ {"id" : "1" , "name" : "Test", "hp" : "112"}
     ];

$('.grid')
  .css(`grid-template-columns`, `repeat(${gridSize}, 4rem)`)
  .html([...Array(gridSize**2)].map(() => '<div class="cell"></div>').join(''));

$('.characters')
  .html(characters.map((character) =>
    `<div class="character"><div class="stats" id ='${character.id}'><p>${character.name}</p><p>hp: ${character.hp}</p></div></div>`).join(``))
  .add('.grid .cell')
  .sortable({
    connectWith: '.characters, .grid .cell',
    cursor: 'grabbing',
    receive: (e, ui) => {
      if(ui.item.parent().hasClass('cell')) {
        let $cell = $(e.target),
            $character = ui.item,
            $characters = $cell.find('.character').not($character),
            coords = [$cell.index() % gridSize, Math.floor($cell.index() / gridSize)];
            coords = coords.toString();
            let characterId = $character.find('.stats').attr('id');
            updateCharacterPosition(characterId, coords)//writes the new pawn's position to the db
            
      }
    }
  });

  function updateCharacterPosition(characterId, coords) {


$.ajax({


    url: "/coords/" + characterId,
    method: 'PATCH',
    data: {
      _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        newcoords: coords
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('Character position updated successfully');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        //It will error because the controller is not present.
    }
});
}
   .grid{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;}
  
.grid .cell{
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: visible;}
  
.grid .cell:has(.character):hover{
  border-width: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;}
  
.characters{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
  min-width: 6rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;}
 
.character{
  align-items: end;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  height: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 3rem;}
  
.character .stats{
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 4px;}

.character p{
  font-size: .66rem;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;}
<div class="grid"></div>
<div class="characters"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>




For pawns and animation you'd be better off using WebGL. Research OGL and WebGL

.attr('id'); should probably bev.prop('id');  but you should also ensure you are not attempting to insert a duplicate ID which would be invalid HTML and not work properly id ='${character.id}'

Please update to include the function code for updateCharacterPosition(characterId, coords) function which you do not have defined here.

I don't think you will find adding the ajax request for updating the coordinates to the database useful but well, I added it anyway.

First, let's see the example:


let gridSize = 7,
//characters array is empty usually because it gets all the pawn infos from the db
     characters = [ {"id" : "1" , "name" : "Test", "hp" : "112"}
     ];

$('.grid')
  .css(`grid-template-columns`, `repeat(${gridSize}, 4rem)`)
  .html([...Array(gridSize**2)].map((i, j) => '<div class="cell">' + (((j % gridSize === 3) && (parseInt(j / gridSize) === 2)) ? `<div class="character ui-sortable-handle" style=""><div class="stats" id="1"><p>Test</p><p>hp: 112</p></div></div>` : "") + '</div>').join(''));

$('.characters')
  .html(characters.map((character) =>
    `<div class="character"><div class="stats" id ='${character.id}'><p>${character.name}</p><p>hp: ${character.hp}</p></div></div>`).join(``))
  .add('.grid .cell')
  .sortable({
    connectWith: '.characters, .grid .cell',
    cursor: 'grabbing',
    receive: (e, ui) => {
      if(ui.item.parent().hasClass('cell')) {
        let $cell = $(e.target),
            $character = ui.item,
            $characters = $cell.find('.character').not($character),
            coords = [$cell.index() % gridSize, Math.floor($cell.index() / gridSize)];
            coords = coords.toString();
            let characterId = $character.find('.stats').attr('id');
            updateCharacterPosition(characterId, coords)//writes the new pawn's position to the db
            
      }
    }
  });

  function updateCharacterPosition(characterId, coords) {


$.ajax({


    url: "/coords/" + characterId,
    method: 'PATCH',
    data: {
      _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        newcoords: coords
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('Character position updated successfully');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        //It will error because the controller is not present.
    }
});
}
.grid{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;}
  
.grid .cell{
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: visible;}
  
.grid .cell:has(.character):hover{
  border-width: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;}
  
.characters{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
  min-width: 6rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: fit-content;}
 
.character{
  align-items: end;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  height: 3rem;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 3rem;}
  
.character .stats{
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 4px;}

.character p{
  font-size: .66rem;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;}
<div class="grid"></div>
<div class="characters"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



Now, the explanation:
  .html([...Array(gridSize**2)].map((i, j) => '<div class="cell">' + (((j % gridSize === 3) && (parseInt(j / gridSize) === 2)) ? `<div class="character ui-sortable-handle" style=""><div class="stats" id="1"><p>Test</p><p>hp: 112</p></div></div>` : "") + '</div>').join(''));

Here, the .html() specifies what needs to be in the HTML and we pass a text to it. The text is generated by the creation of an array of the size of gridSize * gridSize and mapping each element to the HTML template we want. If j is to be at the column of 3 and the row of 2 (you can use custom, dynamic values loaded from the database), then we put in the inner template. Otherwise we don't. Once we generated each template for the array, we join them into a string and pass this string as a raw HTML to the html() function.

You would be correct, it works like a charm, I had to modify it just a bit in order to put each and every pawn that the database has in its own position but overall the logic and the explanation was flawless. Bounty well deserved, I really couldn't figure it out even with the documentation...

If you're trying to make it so the pawn stays in their coords upon refreshing, you can use
localStorage.setItem("PawnX", "5");
localStorage.setItem("PawnY", "5");

To set the local storage, and then you can use
string PawnXString = localStorage.getItem("PawnX");
string PawnYString = localStorage.getItem("PawnY");

to get it from the local storage, and to convert it back into an int, you can do
int PawnX = parseInt(PawnXString);
int PawnY = parseInt(PawnYString);


I know full well where and how to store the values. The problem is to make each pawn to translate those "raw numbers" into its own coordinates on my sortable grid in order to get to position in every refresh

So, you mean, if your grid is a 5x5, you want it to convert where it is into what square on the grid?

As you can see in the script, the Sortable grid (with the help of "coords" variable is able to tell me in which coordinates is the pawn  just moved. For instance if I move a pawn to the first cell of the grid it outputs "0,0" which means that this pawn I moved is now on the first row and first column. Now, every pawn piece has a row on my database, I am able to store to my database the coordinates of each pawn. The problem is this:

I cannot really make the pawn retrieve it's position. Let's say on the database the pawn1 is on 0,0. It retrieves the number 0,0 from the database, but upon refresh naturally, the pawn's position will reset. I have no idea how to make pawn1 get to it's coordinates.
